# How can i get .txt file path?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, filepath

I mean the txt file in my class folder. And I want to find its path and open the txt file.
How can I find that path?

```
  File ftxtFile = new File(something_in_here+"\\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: hey, you did not give us any clue to help you. First your question is vague and second please always show something you have tried by yourself. that is why you are seeing down vote. :(

Comment: I want to find path of file but path is on the my package folder.I mean file is near my .java classes folder

Comment: try : 
File f = new File(Folder_name_contaning_txt_file+File.separatorChar+"myfile.txt");

Comment: but I dont know where is my folder ok? it is in package folder? do not understand? I dont know the path and I ask it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy reading [Java: Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

PS: In the future you should be more proactive as basic stuff like this easy to find

Comment: I want to find path of file but path is on the my package folder.I mean file is near my .java classes folder –

Comment: You need to explain relationship between your application and text file. Is it a file you creating or you searching for occurrences of file with given name?

Comment: I create a txt file and I want to read it in runtime. My txt is near my .java classes folder. I want to read it but how